# How to cleanly detect deep changes on an object in Angular?

Tags: angular

In the parent component I have an object (in my specific case it is the controls of a FormBuilder's FormGroup) which I pass as an input to the child component.

```
<my-component form="fb.controls"></my-component>
```

In the child component, I define the input:

```
@Input()
form: any;
```

If my child component's template refers to a property of this object, change detection is automatic. For example:

```
<div>{{form.myField}}</div>
```

However, in some cases I need to process the input values and then put something else in the template. I want to avoid having the logic embedded in the template. For a *simple* example, this works, but is not pretty:

```
<div [class]="form ? form.difficulty ? form.difficulty.value == 'easy' ? 'green' : form.difficulty.value == 'hard' ? 'red' : 'orange' : 'brown' : 'black'"></div>
```

The alternatives I've found all have problems.

1. Calling a method in the template means it will be called a bazillion times
2. Adding any code to the parent component, like an event emitter or ngModelChanges, seems to violate separation of concerns and be more complicated than it should be
3. ngOnChanges is not called when only a property on the object changes

I am hoping there is a simple (minimal code in the template) way to have Angular handle the change detection as smoothly as though I were referencing the property explicitly in the template.

Edit: The ideal answer would not depend on the object providing an observable (e.g. valueChanges). Angular does not require this when it does its magic change detection. I would like to reproduce exactly what Angular is doing (when the view references a property on the object), but in my controller.

Comment: What if you change the instance of the object when a change is made?   like `fb.controls = {...fb.controls};`

Comment: That would mean changing the parent component to use ngModelChanges. The desired solution should be local to the child component.

Answer (score 1):

In your case specifically, as we are dealing with a reactive form, I would leverage `valueChanges` to handle logic in the TS. Just subscribe to valueChanges in the child and do whatever logic you need to do. Here is a very simple example of watching the `difficulty` form control value and displaying a ngIf - else template based on the value being `easy` or not:

Parent:

```ts
form: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    difficulty: ['']
  })
}
```

Then pass the form to the child or whatever is in your usecase, maybe a nested formgroup? Here just passing the parent form.

In child just listen to the form value change and map a boolean value to `condition$` observable, `true` or `false` depending on the `difficulty` value:

```ts
@Input() form;
condition$: Observable<boolean>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.condition$ = this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
    // using 'any' just for the sake of the demo... do NOT use any!
    map((value: any) => value.difficulty === 'easy')
  );
}
```

Then the template simply being:

```html
<div *ngIf="condition$ | async; else elseTemplate">
  <p style="color: green">Difficulty is easy!</p>
</div>

<ng-template #elseTemplate>
  <p style="color: red">Difficulty is not set as "easy"</p>
</ng-template>
```

As already mentioned in the beginning, this is a veeeery simple example, but it should showcase what I am suggesting you can do.

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-inpfep?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.html)**

If you are passing a nested formgroup to the child and actually want to listen to changes in parent, that can be achieved too, just adding `parent` before the valueChanges:

```ts
this.condition$ = this.form.parent.valueChanges.pipe(
  // using 'any' just for the sake of the demo... do NOT use any!
  map((value: any) => value.difficulty === 'easy')
);
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jehu1z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.html)**

Comment: This is very helpful, and has gotten me very close. However, the observable only emits when values change, so the child component does not initialize with the current form values.

Comment: I can solve the initialization problem by adding this to the pipe: startWith(this.form.value)

Comment: I spoke too soon. I'm using condition$ in a view element inside an *ngFor, so when ngFor creates a new child (i.e. an item is added) there is another "subscription". This new subscription gets the startWith value, and thus will be incorrect until the next time valueChanges emits.

Comment: An explicit subscribe() (and unsubscribe) is the way to go when using the processed value multiple times. It's nice that the async pipe will automatically subscribe/unsubscribe, but multiple subscriptions is problematic especially with initialization.